# Linux RHEL 7.2 c++, the == test fails

Tags: c++, linux, rhel

I see a problem as follows:
i have a long int to represent a tid , later I check if this is same as current tid  using pthread_self() by a simple check :

```
if(my_cachedTID == pthread_self())
      printf("TIDs match");
else
      printf("TIDs don't match %u : %u ", mycachedTID , pthread_self());
```

Sometimes , I get the output as   "TIDs don't match  123456 : 123456 " 
here 123456  is just for example. What I mean to say is it says  Don't match even though they are actually same values  and same code works most of the time  but sometime it does not.  The case where it says  TIDs don't match i added following code

```
long int diff = my_cachedTID - (long int) pthread_self();
 printf("%u",diff); //prints 0 , which is correct..
```

and I am just not able to figure out .. why the == is failing when it prints the same value for both  and when it is printing the difference is 0.
Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you read [the `pthread_self` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html). Play close attention to [the NOTES section](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html#NOTES).

Comment: my bad ..I really din't pay attention to the notes .. could you add this as answer plz. Thanks